# Is there a way to get count of events in Azure Event Hub consumer group for a particular time period?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

Is there a way to get count of events in Azure Event Hub for a particular time period? I need to get the count of events which come for an hour.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to get it as of now, if you look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kaevans/scaling-azure-event-hubs-processing-with-worker-roles), EventHub is a high-Throughput, low-latency durable stream of events on Azure, so getting a count may be not correct at that given point of time

> unlike queues, there is no concept of queue length in Azure Event Hubs
> because the data is processed as a stream

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the context of this question is correct, as a `consumer group` is just a logical grouping of those reading from an Event Hub and nothing gets published to it.  For the remainder of my thoughts, I'm assuming that the nomenclature was a mistake, and what you're interested in is understanding what events were published to a `partition` of the Event Hub.

There's no available metric or report that I'm aware of that would surface the requested information.  However, assuming that you know the time range that you're interested in, you can write a utility to compute this:

1. Connect one of the consumer types from the Event Hubs SDK of your choice to the partition, using `FromEnqueuedTime` or the equivalent as your starting position.  *([sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample05_ReadingEvents.md#read-events-from-a-partition-starting-from-a-specific-date-and-time))*
2. For each event read, inspect the [EnqueuedTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventdata.enqueuedtime) or equivalent and compare it to the window that you're interested in.
3. If the event was enqueued within your window, increase your count and repeat, starting at #2.   If the event was later than your window, you're done.

The count that you've accumulated would be the number of events that the Event Hubs broker received during that time interval.

**Note:** If you're doing this across partitions, you'll want to read each partition individually and count.  The `ReadEvents` method on the consumer does not guarantee ordering or fairness; it would be difficult to have a deterministic spot to decide that you're done reading.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really just need to know "how many events did my Event Hub receive in a particular hour" - you can take a look at the metrics published by the Event Hub. Be aware that, like mentioned in the other answers, the count might not be 100% accurate given the nature of the system.

Take a look at the `Incoming Messages` metric. If you take this for any given hour, it will give you the count of messages that were received during this time period. You can split the namespace metric by EventHub, and every consumer group will receive every single message, so you should be fine.

This is an example of how it can look in the UI, though you should also be able to export it to a log analytics workspace.

[image: Metrics View]